# Happy Birthday on image, error on php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database and I wanted to make sure that when it was someone's birthday, appeared the writing on the banner.
My script for the banner:

```html
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$host_db='127.0.0.1';
$Login_db='root';
$pwd_db='**********';
$bdd_name='regTS3';

$oggi= date("d/m/Y");

$conn=mysql_connect($host_db,$Login_db,$pwd_db);
mysql_select_db($bdd_name,$conn);



$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `regTS3` WHERE `Anni` = '.$oggi.';');
$Data= Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
 $i=0;
        $Data[$i] =  $row['Nome'];
  $i=$i+1;
}





$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("banner.jpg");

$color = ImageColorAllocate($img, 83, 196, 225);
$color2 = ImageColorAllocate($img, 83, 196, 225);

$font= "./pitt.ttf";
$font2="./verdana.ttf";

$text = date("H:i"); 
$text2 = "Test";

imagettftext($img, 28, 0, 560, 70, $color, $font, $text);
imagettftext($img, 30, 0, -150, 190, $color2, $font2, $Data[0]);

imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

The piece of code with the "while" loop I copied on StackOverflow, in a someone's question, (apart from the "i" variable that was my test), but I did not understand much, I need that after It compares the dates back to me the same name, do not know how to return the name of the person in the row.
to test, I set the current date to a follower, on purpose then there's a user database that in the date column, has the current date.

Comment: You are resetting the value of $i back to zero on each iteration..

Comment: Why don't you just make two banner images, one with "Happy Birthday" on it, and show one or the other?

Comment: lol, i fix now it but not work again

Comment: @ceejayoz because i can use only one banner

Comment: @Flynns82 That doesn't make much sense to me, but OK. You have access to the full database but not the HTML of the page?

Comment: @ceejayoz,i need that when it's the birthday of someone, on the banner appears "happy birthday "name",i cannot create 4563534 image for everyone :D anyway i have full access of everything

Comment: @Flynns82 Still doesn't make sense. If it's their birthday, do `readfile('banner-birthday.jpg');` as a replacement for `$img =` onwards. If it's not, do `readfile('banner-not-birthday.jpg');` Skips all the image manipulation.

Comment: i need that appear happy birthday and the name, i cannot create 321432 image for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this a bit simpler:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Nome FROM `regTS3` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Anni,\'%d%m\') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%d%m\')');
$Data= Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
        $Data[] =  $row['Nome'];
}

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("banner.jpg");

$color = ImageColorAllocate($img, 83, 196, 225);
$color2 = ImageColorAllocate($img, 83, 196, 225);

$font= "./pitt.ttf";
$font2="./verdana.ttf";

$text = date("H:i"); 
$text2 = "Test";

imagettftext($img, 28, 0, 560, 70, $color, $font, $text);
if (count($Data) > 0) {
   $string = implode(" ", $Data);
   imagettftext($img, 30, 0, -150, 190, $color2, $font2, $string);
}
```

Comment: i copied this but not work, on the log: Undefined offset: 0 at line imagettftext($img, 30, 0, -150, 190, $color2, $font2, $Data[0]);

Comment: is possible to edit "DATE(NOW)", i need to put in only day/mounth, i use the current date only for test :D

Comment: The problem was, that you did compare the whole date - but you just need the day and the month to detect someones birthday (see updated code)

Comment: i see the update, anyway, on the db in the column there is "15/01", DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),%d%m) is like "15/01"?

Comment: It does not matter, the MySQL-engine just compares the day (%d) and month (%m) part of your date. The stored date format does not have be the one that you see, as it is locale dependent.

Comment: is possible tu use simply string? columnname = "string"

Comment: Name or data type? I think you mean data type String which would be a `VARCHAR`in MySQL. No, it is not a good idea to use `VARCHAR`for `DATE` or `DATETIME` fields

Comment: lol, sorry, but im not expert of mysql and i see now that exist the DATE Type of a column :D before was set like char, now i set date haha, sorry!! and now work! thanks very much!!

Comment: but, and if there are 2 or more person with the same date? what is the output?

Comment: Then your `$Data`Array will look like this: `Array(0=>'Antonio', 1=>'Fabio', 2=>'Claudia')` - it depends then on what you want to do - add all the names to the same Image? Like the code is now, it would only add 'Antonio'

Comment: yes, all name to the same image, i see on the db that there are 2 person with the same date

Comment: See updated version - now it would print "Antonio Fabio Claudia"

Comment: work, thanks, i edit my registration to it: <td><input tabindex='3' name='giorno' class='application' size='1' value='DD'/>-<input tabindex='4' name='mese' class='application' size='1' value='MM'/>-<input tabindex='5' name='anno' class='application' size='2' value='YYYY'/></td> it is the line to insert the date, after i write that: $anni=''.$anno.'-'.$mese.'-'.$giorno.''; but when i insert $anni on mysql, result 0000-00-00

Comment: Try `$anni = $anno.'-'.$mese.'-'.$giorno;` and check with `echo $anni`if your var really contains what you think it should - and you could of course accept my answer ;)

Comment: i try and the echo return the correct thing but on mysql result anyway 0000-00-00

Comment: and how does your insert query look like?

Comment: $request="INSERT INTO `regTS3`.`regTS3` (`Nome`, `Nickname`, `Anni`,`Email`, `Id`, `Id_Phone`,`Id_2`)
         VALUES ('$nome', '$nickname', '$anni', '$email', NULL, NULL, NULL);";

Comment: The syntax looks ok, the problem must be somewhere else. What does `echo $reqest` tell you?

Comment: its empty o.o : INSERT INTO `regTS3`.`regTS3` (`Nome`, `Nickname`, `Anni`,`Email`, `Id`, `Id_Phone`,`Id_2`) VALUES ('tyertyer', 'rteyert', '', 'ter@reter.it', NULL, NULL, NULL);

Comment: apache log say: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: anni